# Python: How to create a file in a local server?

Tags: python

I am used to connect to a local server by using putty. But now I need to create a file by using a script python, this file has a huge size, so I must put it in local server;

by using puty, I must entre my host adresse, password, name and the port.

How do I do that?

This is my script:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
P_Result_File_Path ="Path_To_the_Result_File"
Folder_path =r'Path_To_my_numpy_files'  
os.chdir(Folder_path)
npfiles= glob.glob("*.npy")
npfiles.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
print (npfiles)
loadedFiles = [np.load(npf) for npf in npfiles]
PArray=np.concatenate(loadedFiles, axis=0 )
np.save(Power_Result_File_Path, PArray)
```

`P_Result_File_Path`  file has a huge size, so I need to save it in a local server, the problem in this case that `Path_To_the_Result_File= /home/user/result.npy`, so this path is unknown, I need to connect to this server in order to create and put the resulted file.

Comment: You can ssh into the server and run your python script there if you don't want to copy the file from one machine to another. Is there something specific you're looking for here?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla Thank you for youe answer, could please see the edited question ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is edited due to the changes in question.

**If you don't want to store the P_Result_File_Path on your local machine even temporarily:**

I would advice you to copy the python script file to the server first, and execute it there (as stated by @Sudheesh Singanamalla). In order to copy your python script, please, take a look at scp - http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php):

Copy the directory "foo" from the local host to a remote host's directory "bar"

```
$ scp -r foo your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory/bar
```

Or vice versa, you can copy the script at the server from local machine.
And then you can execute your python script and store your P_Result_File_Path in the server directly

**But if you want to create P_Result_File_Path in your local machine first, and then send it to the server:**

Execute your python script on local machine, and then scp resulting file to the server.

Hope, this will help

Update (since resulting file should be stored to the server during Python script execution on local machine) - as an idea, you can use FTP for this:

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('<your_server_address>','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
session.storbinary('STOR <file_to_send>', PArray)
```

And if you will still get error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed, it is easy to google why this mistake happened

Comment: thank you for your answer, it gives me this error:                         for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: if the OP is already connecting to the server using SSH, wouldn't it be simpler to just send the file using `scp` or something instead of invoking another python script just to send the file via FTP?

Comment: @Simon , I am already connnected using SSH, but I don't like to create the file in my desktop, then move it to the local server, I need to create ans save the resulted file directly in the server.

Comment: @Olia I copied the script in my local server, but the problem is that I must change those paths: P_Result_File_Path = "Path_To_the_Result_File" Folder_path =r'Path_To_my_numpy_files' , So the error if I keep my actual paths is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: It means that I must move my folder of files in the local server, but for me I need to keep my forlder which contains my files in my local machine (In fact I have a huge number of files), so really I don't know what to do?

Comment: @Guillaume, if you copied python script to the server, and you execute it there, the path(Path_To_the_Result_File) should be according to your server filesystem.

Comment: @Guillaume, but if you need to execute Python script on your local machine, since, as I see, you have some numpy files here, just execute Python script and create P_Result_File_Path in your local machine, and then scp resulting file to the server.

Comment: @Olia, the path to my result file is of course in the local server, but the path to all my numpy files which I must concatenate must be in my local machine. So the solution that you proposed to me requires that all paths must be in the local server. Is it clear please???

Comment: @Guillaume, you need to store the resulting file to local server, but your numpy files are on local machine and python script should be executed on local machine because of those files? So, this resulting file should be stored to the server during Python script execution, yes?

Comment: @Olia, yes exactly.

Comment: @Guillaume can you set up ftp or http server on local server in order to send the file?

Comment: @Olia, I use already FTP.

Answer (score 1):

If your remote server is able to connect to your local machine (i.e. the computer you're on), then you can try the following:

1. SSH into your server
2. Use scp to copy the file from your local machine to your server:

   - `scp local_user@local_ip:/path/to/local/python/script.py /server/path/for/saved/file.py`
   - scp takes the following syntax: `scp <source> <destination>`. In this case, the source is your local machine, and destination is your server, but given you're already logged into the server, you need to supply the login information for your local machine
3. Once the python script has been copied to your server, just run it with `python /server/path/for/saved/file.py` while you're still connected via SSH. Just make sure the path in your python script is a viable path on your server

   - This should generate the results file on the server directly so you dont need to transfer it

In the event that your remote server can't access your local machine, then there are a number of things you can do to get the python script to your server:

- Upload the file somewhere (e.g. dropbox) and get a link. SSH into the server and `wget http://link-to-file.py` to pull the python file to your server. Then like above, run it using python directly on the server or...
- On your local machine, use some terminal to transfer using scp, but this time in the other direction:

  - `scp /path/to/local/python/script.py server_user@server_ip:/server/path/for/saved/file.py`
  - Side note: scp will create its own ssh connection so you'd want to run that first *before* you manually ssh into the server to run the python file

Comment: I copied the script in my local server, but the problem is that I must change those paths: P_Result_File_Path = "Path_To_the_Result_File"  Folder_path =r'Path_To_my_numpy_files' , So the error if I keep my actual paths is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: It means that I must move my folder of files in the local server, but for me I need to keep my forlder which contains my files in my local machine (In fact I have a huge number of files), so really I don't know what to ddo?

Comment: I need to put all the resulted file in my local server

Comment: In that case you would have to set the paths in your python file to paths on your local machine (i.e. `P_Result_File_Path` has to be a local path), and run the script locally to get a results file on your computer. Then scp the *results* file to the server in the same way as above (i.e. instead of scp the python script, scp the results)